# How efficient is it to order by distance in geodjango (entire table)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geodjango

Assume that I have the following data model:

```
Person(models.Model):
    id       = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

Assume also that I have an app that queries a Django backend, the only function of the app is to return a list of registered users sorted from closest to farthest in a paginated format.

Currently I have the following query in mind:

```
# here we are obtaining all users in ordered form
current_location = me.location
people = Person.objects.distance(current_location).order_by('distance')

# here we are obtaining the first X through pagination
start_index = a
end_index = b

people = people[a:b]
```

Although this works, it is not as fast as I would like.

I have worries about the speed of this query. If the table was extensive (over 1 million), wouldn't the Postgres SQL database with PostGIS have to calculate the distance between the `current_location` and every `location` in the database prior to sorting the subsequent 1 million rows through an `order_by` operation?

Can anyone suggest a more efficient alternative method for retrieving and sorting nearby users based on distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort every entry on that table by distance then it will be slow as expected and there is nothing that can be done (that I am aware of at this point of time and my knowledge.)!

You can make your calculation more efficient by following this steps and making some assumptions:

1. Enable [spatial indexing](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html#section-8-spatial-indexing) on your tables. To do that in GeoDjango, follow [the doc instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups) and fit them to your model:

   > Note
   >
   > In PostGIS, ST_Distance_Sphere does not limit the geometry types geographic distance queries are performed with. [[4]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#fndistsphere15) However, these queries may take a long time, as great-circle distances must be calculated on the fly for every row in the query. This is because the spatial index on traditional geometry fields cannot be used.
   >
   > For much better performance on WGS84 distance queries, consider using [geography columns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type) in your database instead because they are able to use their spatial index in distance queries. You can tell GeoDjango to use a geography column by setting `geography=True` in your field definition.
2. Now you can narrow down your query with some logical constrains:

   *Ex:* My user will not look for people more than 50km from his current position.
3. Narrow down the search using [`dwithin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin) spatial lookup which utilizes the above mentioned [spatial indexing](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html#section-8-spatial-indexing), therefore it is pretty fast.
4. Finally apply the `distance` order by on the remaining rows.

The final query can look like this:

```
current_location = me.location
people = People.objects.filter(
    location__dwithin=(current_location, D(km=50))
).annotate(
    distance=Distance('location', current_location)
).order_by('distance')
```

---

**P.S:** Rather than creating a custom pagination attempt, it is more efficient to utilize the pagination methods provided for the django views:

- [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/)

Or you can use Django Rest Framework and use it's pagination:

- [Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) and a [DRF pagination Q&A example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670648/how-to-use-pagination-in-a-non-generic-view-viewset)

Comment: I wanted to use `OGRGeometry` as it has a constructor that can take a location string like `'SRID=4326;POINT (-122 37)'` but you can't use this as an arg to `dwithin`. Make sure to use a `django.contrib.gis.geos.Point` for `current_location`.