# How do I get the k nearest neighbors for geodjango?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

Assume that I have the following model:

```
class Person:
     id       = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
     name     = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     location = models.PointField()
```

How would I go by obtaining the k nearest neighbors (KNN) by location using geodjango? 
Would I have to write custom SQL for that? 
I am using PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) sql query to utilize postgis `order_by` operators:

1. [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) which gets the nearest neighbor using the centers of the bounding boxes to calculate the inter-object distances.
2. [`<#>`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_box.html) which gets the nearest neighbor using the bounding boxes themselves to calculate the inter-object distances.

In your case the one you want seems to be the `<->` operator, thus the raw query:

```
knn = Person.objects.raw(
    'SELECT * FROM myapp_person 
    ORDER BY location <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),4326)',
    [location.x, location.y]
)[:k]
```

*EDIT due to own derpiness:* You can omit the `[:k]` to add `LIMIT 1` on the raw SQL query. (Don't use both as I did!)

---

In the process of answering your other question: [How efficient is it to order by distance (entire table) in geodjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383792/how-efficient-is-it-to-order-by-distance-entire-table-in-geodjango/) ,another solution maybe possible:

By enabling `spatial indexing` and narrowing down your query through logical constrains (as explained [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383792/how-efficient-is-it-to-order-by-distance-entire-table-in-geodjango/45433627#45433627) of the above -linked question) you can achieve a pretty fast **KNN** query as follows:

```
current_location = me.location
people = People.objects.filter(
    location__dwithin=(current_location, D(km=50))
).annotate(
    distance=Distance('location', current_location)
).order_by('distance')[:k]
```

Comment: For this scenario (obtaining knn), would it be still helpful to use a geography column? Or would it be pointless - since I am assuming the calculations involving `<->` would be different

Comment: You can use a geography column or a geometry one. What matters on speeding up your query is to use `spatial_idex`.
For further reading on the subject, have a look here: https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/
Good luck @Alan :)

Comment: Hello, looking back at your answer, I am confused by the purpose of `LIMIT 1` in `knn = Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person...`, why do we need that?

Comment: @Alan That will return the first nearest neighbor. You can change it at will! I will edit this in my answer as well.

Comment: I thought `[:k]` took care of that? I am confused since `LIMIT K` and `[:k]` seem to be serving the same purpose here

Comment: @Alan that is correct... I totally derped on that! I will correct it :)

Comment: I would advise using an f string to avoid hardcoding the table name: knn = Person.objects.raw(
    f'SELECT * FROM {People._meta.db_table} 
    ORDER BY location <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),4326)',
    [location.x, location.y]
)[:k]