# GeoDjango - distance between a point and a queryset of multipolygons

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I'm familiar with Django, but new to GeoDjango and PostGIS.

I have a problem where I want to find the nearest MuliPolygon to a point. The point can be outside or within the MultiPolygon. Nearest means the nearest boundary point.

I know that I can calculate the distance between two points with `from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance` - but I don't want to use the `centroid` because it is possible the border of a MultiPolygon is closer to one point than the `centroid` of another.

I have a model `Land` with a field `surface_area` which is a `MultiPolygon`. I have a point object created with `from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point`. This is the data I'm using to try and build a query.

Any help with best practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

GeoDjango's [distance lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups) utilize the corresponding database's distance function.

Since you are using PostgreSQL with PostGIS the corresponding [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) method:

> For geometry types returns the minimum 2D Cartesian (planar) distance between two geometries, in projected units (spatial ref units).

Therefore you can use the [distance lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups) for your calculations.

If you want to implement it a bit differently (for example using the bounding boxes of the polygons) you can refer to this Q&A: [How do I get the k nearest neighbors for geodjango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405183/how-do-i-get-the-k-nearest-neighbors-for-geodjango/45433178#45433178)