# GeoDjango: Finding objects in radius

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gis, geodjango

I'm currently trying to get a list of points contained within a radius but I can't get it working. Here is the code of my view so far:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

class AreaInfoViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = models.AreaInfoRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AreaInfoRequestRequestSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        center_point = 'POINT(48.80033 2.49175)'
        radius = "50.0"

        data = {"center_point": center_point, "radius": radius, "source_ip": utils.get_client_ip(request)}
        serializer = serializers.AreaInfoRequestRequestSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        # Contains an object with field "from_location"="SRID=4326;POINT (48.80029 2.49157)"
        objs = models.PointsResult.objects.all()

        float_radius = serializer.data["radius"]
        center_point = serializer.data["center_point"] # Point object

        res = models.PointsResult.objects.filter(from_location__distance_lte=(
            center_point, Distance({"meter": float_radius})))
        # Here the res doesn't contain the unique object in the db even if it's within the radius

        return Response(res)
```

Any idea why it's not working? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe that you run into a similar problem to the one described here: [GeoDjango & SpatiaLite - filtering nearby objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948532/geodjango-spatialite-filtering-nearby-objects/45751909#45751909)

First things first I would suggest using [`dwithin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-dwithin) instead of `distance_lte` for the filtering because it is optimized for that use (a very sort explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383792/how-efficient-is-it-to-order-by-distance-entire-table-in-geodjango/45433627#45433627))

From the `dwithin` docs we read:

> Returns models where the distance to the geometry field from the
>   lookup geometry are within the given distance from one another. **Note
>   that you can only provide Distance objects if the targeted geometries
>   are in a projected system. For geographic geometries, you should use
>   units of the geometry field (e.g. degrees for WGS84).**

Therefore you must change your query to something like this:

```
meters_to_degrees = CONVERT YOUR METERS TO DEGREES
res = models.PointsResult.objects.filter(
    from_location__dwithin=(center_point, meters_to_degrees)
)
```

A calculation of meters (specifically of km) to degrees can be found here: [How do I convert kilometres to degrees in Geodjango/GEOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217348/how-do-i-convert-kilometres-to-degrees-in-geodjango-geos?answertab=votes#tab-top)

As a final note, on a DRF perspective, you are doing a model instance creation inside the `list` method of the `ViewSet`. **That is absolutely wrong and should be avoided.** You should override the `create` method if you like to interfere with the object creation process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response! I think this is what I was looking for, will try this shortly. Also thanks for the DRF suggestion, I'll change this view to APIView and use a `get` instead

Comment: @E-Kami happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see two issues here:

1. You haven't specified the SRID on your center point, which means you're comparing two different SRIDs. You need to set the SRID on `center_point`:

   ```
   center_point = 'SRID=4326;POINT(48.80033 2.49175)'
   ```
2. Your inline comment says `POINT (2.49157 48.80029)`, but your code uses `POINT(48.80033 2.49175)` - note that the latitude and longitude have swapped places. I don't know which of these you intend to use, but they refer to quite different locations.

Comment: Sorry I swapped the two after an experiment. The actual one is actually not swapped. I edited my question and fixed this issue.

Comment: Even using `center_point = 'SRID=4326;POINT(48.80033 2.49175)'` doesn't work and I believe by default `SRID=4326` is used on all `Point` object I create

Comment: Please provide sample data for the points you expect to match?

Comment: The one in the comment should be found:
```
# Contains an object with field "from_location"="SRID=4326;POINT (48.80029 2.49157)"
        objs = models.PointsResult.objects.all()
```