# How to find only the distance to the closest linestring from a polygon in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have some land parcel polygons and I have some powerline linestrings. For each parcel, I'm trying to find only the distance to the closest linestring.

This query runs but takes quite a long time:

```
SELECT 
  a.OBJECTID,
  st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) as distance

FROM `kpennell.KYLETEST.parcelpoly` a
join `kpennell.KYLETEST.powerlines` b
ON st_dwithin(a.geometry, b.geometry, 1000)
```

I'm guessing I need to use [Paul Ramsay](https://carto.com/blog/lateral-joins/) Or [Michael Entin's nearest neighbors](https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-in-bigquery-gis-7d50ebd5d63) things, but I can't seem to get the query right. The latter example finds just the id of the closest one but not the actual distance (I think).

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(b.id ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.geog, b.geog) LIMIT 1)
      [ORDINAL(1)] as neighbor_id
FROM people_table a JOIN restaurant_table b
ON ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geom, 100) -- 100 is search radius
GROUP BY a.id
```

The Parcels are Polygons with a unique object id
[image: parcels]

The Powerlines are linestrings with a unique object id [image]

What I'm hoping to find, for each parcel, is the parcel, and then the distance to the closest powerline. So for each parcel, I  want to get the parcel OBJECTID and then distance to the closest powerline.

I'm trying to do this efficiently where it stops when it finds the nearest neighbor for each one.

Comment: Could you provide the schema/sample data of your table(s) and expected output for easy replication?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Thx, I just added an edit

Answer (score 2):

We can combine the distance with the id using a [`STRUCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct_type):

```
SELECT 
  poly.id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(pline.id, ST_Distance(poly.geog, pline.geog)) 
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(poly.geog, pline.geog) LIMIT 1
  ) [ORDINAL(1)] as neighbor
FROM 
    `kpennell.KYLETEST.parcelpoly` poly JOIN 
    `kpennell.KYLETEST.powerlines` pline ON 
     ST_DWithin(poly.geog, pline.geom, 100) -- 100 is search radius
GROUP BY poly.id
```

---

There are other options though:

If we know the `parcelpoly` id before the query (from an input form etc.) we can have a simplified query:

```
SELECT 
  poly.id,
  pline.id,
  st_distance(poly.geometry, pline.geometry) as distance
FROM `kpennell.KYLETEST.parcelpoly` AS poly,
     `kpennell.KYLETEST.powerlines` AS pline
WHERE poly.id = <known_parcelpoly_id> AND st_dwithin(poly.geometry, pline.geometry, 1000)
ORDER BY st_distance(poly.geometry, pline.geometry) 
LIMIT 1
```

Finally, we can use PostGIS's [knn operator (`<->`)](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html):

```
SELECT 
  poly.id,
  pline.id,
  st_distance(poly.geometry, pline.geometry) as distance
FROM `kpennell.KYLETEST.parcelpoly` AS poly,
     `kpennell.KYLETEST.powerlines` AS pline
WHERE poly.id = <known_parcelpoly_id> AND st_dwithin(poly.geometry, pline.geometry, 1000)
ORDER BY poly.geometry <-> pline.geometry
LIMIT 1
```

**There is a caveat though here!**
The `<->` operator:

> For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies.

which means that for PostgreSQL < 9.5 we may lose accuracy with that method.

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, still not quite getting it to work in BigQuery

Comment: @KylePennell is there an error? Or a different behavior?

Comment: Some might have a distance of 0 but there's a lot of parcels and some should be more than that

Comment: @KylePennell What srid are you using? Does it use meters or degrees?

Comment: Should be EPSG:4326 WGS 84

Comment: @KylePennell `ST_Dwithin` uses the units of the SRID for geometries, so your query is in degrees.
Here is an explanation on why this is an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137122/geodjango-finding-objects-in-radius/57270114#57270114.
That is also true for `ST_Distance` so those `0.0`s there are probably truncated distances in degrees.

Comment: I think st_distance returns the shortest distance in meters between two non-empty GEOGRAPHYs. ST_dwithin also work with meters 'The given distance is in meters on the surface of the Earth.' 

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance

Comment: @KylePennell Yeah seems true :/ Have you checked that your data are GEOGRAPHY type and not GEOMETRY (just to make sure)?

Comment: Yeah, they seem to be geography. Any other ideas?