# geodjango spatial lookup failure Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries

Tags: django, geospatial, postgis, geodjango

So I'm building Django app which has some stores saved with coordinates in db, all I need to do, when I get user coordinates, I want to search in db for the nearest store,
IDk what to do after receiving coordinates eveything raises error

tried this hard coded query lookup

```
Shop.objects.filter(location__dwithin  = (GEOSGeometry(Point(-95.23592948913574, 38.97127105172941)), D(km=5)))
```

but still getting errors like

> Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries.

the srid if it matters is 4326, idk even know what this is

Comment: Pedantic note: do you really that precision? With this coordinates you're entering the microscopy realm `-95.23592948913574`  ;)

Comment: idk, it's just random coordinates from the internet :"D

Comment: There is an answer to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137122/geodjango-finding-objects-in-radius/57270114#57270114 
"For geographic geometries, you should use units of the geometry field (e.g. degrees for WGS84)"